# Error message "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`. I want to add column 4 values. I wrote this code. But it shows above error on `Total += Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);`.

```
 decimal Total = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
      dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = 
          Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value) * 
          Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

          Total += Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
 }
 lblFinalTotalAdd.Text = Total.ToString();
```

***Creating 5th column code:***

```
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conn);
            con.Open();
            DataTable dtusers = new DataTable();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select Shorts,Code,Description,Percentage from SalesFields", con);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dtusers);
            dgvSalesFooterAdd.DataSource = dtusers;
            dgvSalesFooterAdd.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
            dgvSalesFooterAdd.Columns[0].Name = "Shorts";
            dgvSalesFooterAdd.Columns[1].Name = "Code";
            dgvSalesFooterAdd.Columns[2].Name = "Description";
            dgvSalesFooterAdd.Columns[3].Name = "Percentage";
            dgvSalesFooterAdd.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Shorts";
            dgvSalesFooterAdd.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Code";
            dgvSalesFooterAdd.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Description";
            dgvSalesFooterAdd.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Percentage";
            DataGridViewColumn amount = new DataGridViewColumn();
            amount.HeaderText = "Amount";
            amount.Name = "Amount";
            amount.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            dgvSalesFooterAdd.Columns.Insert(4, amount);
            con.Close();

            con.Close();
```

Comment: Are you sure its 4 and not 3?

Comment: verify your dgvSalesBodyAdd.Rows[i].Cells.Count

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis: In this Datagrid first 4 column value[column0, column1,column2,clounm3] came from database. I add a extra column[column4]. In that case column3 values are multiply and store in column4. Now I want to add these column4 values.

Comment: Where is the code that you created the "fifth" column?

Comment: You cycle over the rows of `dgvSalesFooterAdd`, yet you try to write into `dgSalesBodyAdd`. Do you have the same amount of **rows** in both `DataGridView`s ?

Comment: @BartFriederichs:: That is not my problem. My problem  on next line. Ok I'll update my question.

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis: I edit my code. Here you can see how I add 5th column.

Comment: @AnimeshGhosh there is a "Watch" in the visual studio debugger. Use it to inspect the actual values and columns of your `DataGridView`.

Comment: I don't see where you set the cell value for [4]

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis: Cell 4 value provided by user.

Answer (score 1):

C#'s arrays are zero-based. This means the first element is element 0. The 4th element is element 3.

You probably have only four columns, numbered 0 to 3.

Comment: I know. I have 5 column. So I add column4.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 decimal Total = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
      dgvSalesBodyAdd.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = 
          Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesBodyAdd.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value) * 
          Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesBodyAdd.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);

          Total += Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSalesFooterAdd.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
 }
 lblFinalTotalAdd.Text = Total.ToString();
```

Comment: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"